# Calculate complexity of an algorithm which uses HashTable

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity

I need to calculate the complexity of this algorithm, which uses the `HashTables`. It should be `O(logn)`, is it correct? Does the usage of the `HashTables` change something when I calculate the complexity?

```
protected static int distanceDyn(String s1, String s2, Hashtable <Pair<String, String>, Integer> dictionary) {
    int no_op, min;
    if (dictionary.containsKey(new Pair<String, String>(s1, s2)))
        return dictionary.get(new Pair<String, String>(s1, s2));

    if (s1 == null || s2 == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    if (s1.length() == 0) {
        dictionary.put(new Pair<String, String> (s1, s2), s2.length());
        return s2.length();
    }

    if (s2.length() == 0) {
        dictionary.put(new Pair<String, String> (s1, s2), s1.length());
        return s1.length();
    }

    if (s1.charAt(0)==s2.charAt(0)) no_op = distanceDyn(s1.substring(1), s2.substring(1), dictionary);
    else no_op = -1;

    int del = 1 + distanceDyn(s1, s2.substring(1), dictionary);
    int ins = 1 + distanceDyn(s1.substring(1), s2, dictionary);
    if (no_op == -1) {
        dictionary.put(new Pair<String, String> (s1, s2), Math.min(del, ins));
        return Math.min(del, ins);
    } else 
    min = Math.min(del, Math.min(ins, no_op));
    dictionary.put(new Pair<String, String> (s1, s2), min);
    return min;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, it seems its the dynamic programming approach for edit distance algorithm.

Firstly, the complexity of dynamic programming approach for edit distance is `O(n * m)` where `n` and `m` are the lengths of two strings, its not possible to be anywhere close to `O(logn)`.

Secondly, here a `HashTable` has been used. If it was a `HashMap`, the operation on `HashMap` won't affect the total complexity calculation because insertion/search is amortized `O(1)`. For hashtable, it will be little slower because `HashTable` is thread safe. And for this problem, I am not seeing any necessity of using `HashTable` instead of `HashMap`. However, asymptotically, the complexity is still `O(n * m)` anyway.

Comment: Which complexity is O(n+m)? Time should be O(n*m), right?

Comment: @AndreiDamian-Fekete Ops, it was a serious typo. Thanks for pointing out :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems this algorithm finds a distance between two strings. Complexity of `put()` and `get()` methods of `Hashtable` is `O(1)`, but here you use recursion. So the `distanceDyn()` method will be invoked `kN` times in worst case scenario, where `N` equal to multiplication of lengths of `s1` and `s2` and `k` is a constant. In terms of asymptotic complexity it's `O(N)` as coefficients are not taken into account.